# Quotient Module notation

Tags: notation, modules

This is a pretty elementary concept that I somehow managed to coast by without understanding fully; Why do we write the elements of a quotient module $(m + N) \in M/N$ (where $M$ is some $R$-module, $N \subseteq M$ and $m \in M$)?

From my understanding the $M/N$ module refers to all the set containing all the elements in $M$ that is *not* in $N$. Where does the '+' symbol come into play then? What does it mean to "add" an element $m$ to the set $N$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reasonable misunderstanding: you're thinking of the set difference operation, which can be written $M-N$ or $M\setminus N$ (and maybe sometimes also $M/N$). But here the notation $M/N$ is defined to mean the set of equivalence classes that comprise the quotient module.

In general, if we have an element $m$ and a set $N$, the expression $m+N$ is defined to mean $\{m+n\colon n\in N\}$.